# String found, numeric expected in Oracle function called from Java

Tags: java, oracle, function, package

**EDIT**

Putting this here in case it helps others. My problem was a failure in understanding how PreparedStatement works. I had believed that the "?"...setInt() syntax was a simple substitution that constructs an SQL statement, interprets it and sends *that* to the DB, which is not the case. The answers below explain in detail the problem.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm having some trouble getting an Oracle package function call to execute from within a Java app. I am receiving the below error:

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

I believe I have constructed the call correctly, and the only place I'm using a string is for a date field (not a numeric one). The function has the signature:

```
function f_get_mr_target(a_plan_id number,a_machine number,a_shift_id number,a_shift_dt date) return number;
```

My java code invoking the function is as follows:

```
public Double checkMRTarget(int planId, int machineNum, int shiftId, String date)
{
    //Instantiate the return value
    Double mrTarget = null;

    //Get the MR target
    try
    {
        //Ready the connection
        con = nativeDataSource.getConnection();

        //The query string
        String sql = "select pkg_bcs.f_get_mr_target(?,?,?,?) target from dual";

        //Prepare the query
        stmt = null;
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setInt(1, planId);
        stmt.setInt(2, machineNum);
        stmt.setInt(3, shiftId);
        stmt.setString(4, date);

        //Execute the query
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        //Extract the value from the result set
        mrTarget = rs.getDouble("target");
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    { 
        System.out.println("Error getting mrTarget: " + e); 
    }
    finally
    { closeDBConnections(); }

    //Return the value
        return mrTarget;
}
```

Con is a public Connection object shared by all other methods in the class. Stmt is a PreparedStatement object, also shared. The parameters are passed as follows:

```
planId = 986548
machineNum = 5227
shiftId = 10
date = "trunc(sysdate)"
```

I've verified that running

```
select pkg_bcs.f_get_mr_target(986548, 5227, 10, trunc(sysdate)) target from dual;
```

works just fine in SQLDeveloper. As far as I can tell, it's getting a number where it expects a number

Comment: What makes you think you can pass the string `trunc(sysdate)` to a parameter that expects a `Date` type?  Parameter substitution is strongly typed, you cannot just pass arbitrary SQL text for a `Date` parameter.

Comment: It was evidently a misunderstanding of how the PreparedStatement works. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for explaining the problem in much organized way. !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've called `setString`, so Java sent a `String` that Oracle can't implicitly convert into a `DATE`.

You can convert it to a `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Time`, or `java.sql.Timestamp` by first parsing the date with a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), and creating the appropriate object, and calling `setDate`, `setTime`, or `setTimestamp` instead of `setString`.

Alternatively, you can get Oracle to convert it by calling [`to_date`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132) in your JDBC SQL:

```
// Your date format may vary.
String sql = "select pkg_bcs.f_get_mr_target(?,?,?,to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) target from dual";
```

Answer (score 1):

the 4th parameter which is date do not work with String. It waits for a Date object.

Here is your method signature, pass a Date object instead of String.

```
public Double checkMRTarget(int planId, int machineNum, int shiftId, Date date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Substituting a string datatype to a Date parameter is a catastrophe. It will surely the `ORA-01858` exception in this case (in context of you code).

Parameter substitution demands exact binding which serves its purpose of being strongly typed. 
Please convert the fourth parameter i.e. the `string` parameter into a `date object`. & then implement what you wish to. It should work fine then.

Also, `trunc(sysdate)` in SQL query does not return a string to the SQL client. Rather it returns the date(internal conversion). This is designed such that the parser recognize the date type efficiently and consistently.